# Expectation of idempotent matrix multiplied by error vector

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression

I have a $T \times T$  idempotent and symmetric matrix $M_X$, defined as $M_X$ = $I_T - X(X'X)^{-1}X'$, where $X$ is a $T \times K$ matrix of $T$ observations of $K$ regressors.

For the following simple regression model:

$y_t$ = $β_1$ + $β_2x_t$ + $ε_t$

Where the vector of REAL errors (not model residuals) is **$ε$**, I want to prove that the expectation of the square of the product of the idempotent matrix and the error vector is equal to the expectation of a quadratic form of the two, i.e. proving that:

$E((M_Xε)'(M_Xε))$ = $E(ε'M_Xε)$

I am not sure why this is the case - I suspect it has to do with the property of idempotence, but trying it with sample values seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: $ (M_X\epsilon)'(M_X\epsilon) = (\epsilon'M_X')(M_X \epsilon) = \epsilon' M_X^2 \epsilon = \epsilon' M_X \epsilon $. This is the reason for $ E((M_X\epsilon)'(M_X\epsilon)) = E(\epsilon' M_X \epsilon) $.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot my standard matrix transpose properties, oops!